# List default Page Size for windows printer devices

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, wmi, windows-server

I would like to be able to get the default page size of all windows printer devices on a windows server (2003 in this instance).

This should be not the DefaultPageSize property on the Win32_Printer WMI object, but that which is set via the printer driver.

The printer driver is the Adobe Generic PostScript Driver.

Answer (score 0):

The printer configuration provided by the print driver is located in the registry at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\<printer name>\
```

This does *not* appear to be the same as the Current and Default Paper Size properties on the Win32_Printer WMI object.

The "Default DevMode" property is a binary representation of a number of settings for the device. Open the property in the modify window to see an ascii representation.

To extract this field I used the following:

```
Get-ItemProperty -path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\* | ForEach-Object{ $_.name, [string]::Join($null, ($_."Default DevMode" | %{ [char][int]$_;})) } > .\printer_driver_properties.txt
```

The Default DevMode property is converted to a character array which is then converted to a string.

Open the resulting file in encoding aware editor such as notepad.exe. In my experience it was unicode double byte characters.

For each printer there should be a number of properties, including:

- Name
- Resolution
- PageSize
- PageRegion
- InputSlot

Note: This was a quick hack to retrieve this information. If there is a more correct way of doing this, or you'd like to suggest something else to tidy it up I'd be most appreciative.

Also, if there is a resource or specification on this area of the registry please let me know!